# How can I use conditional operator for rowspan and colspan in nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js

I am using Vue.Js and also using Nuxt.js as framework

I really want to create a table like this using data from a database table, with rowspan and colspan

and for the data taken from the table in the database
the example is in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Conditional operator for rowspan

```
<tr>
  <td :rowspan="hasRowspan ? 2 : 1">Cell 1</td>
  <td>Cell 2</td>
  <td>Cell 3</td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      condition: true 
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).